# Servlet context serializable attribute persistence

Tags: java, servlets

I set a servlet context attribute, which is an object of Serializable class. Does it persist after application server restart as session attributes do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in servlet contexts are not automatically persisted.  If you want to persist them you will need to do it yourself.

I don't think persistence of servlet context attributes would be a good idea.  There is a non-zero chance that the servlet container will terminate abruptly without giving your webapp a chance to persist its attributes.  Your webapp would need to deal with this possibility on restart.

Answer (score 1):

This is not required/specified by the Servlet API. Technically, this depends on the servletcontainer in question. As far as I know, no one does that. You'd like to consult the documentation of the servletcontainer in question. If it doesn't support that, then you need to persist and revive it *yourself* with help of a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).