# Keep servlet context in Grails after container reboot

Tags: grails, servlets, reboot

After restarting my tomcat instance all properties of servlet context are being lost, although all active sessions are still being aroung with their properties alive and kicking. What's the best - and most Grails-like - way to make servlet context properties survive a container reboot?

Comment: Just so that it's completely clear can you please specify the manner in which you are "reboot"'ing the container?

Comment: what I'm doing in the end - via a few detours - is 'tomcat_base/bin/shutdown' and 'tomcat_base/bin/startup'

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no real Grails'ish way to do that. Following the Standard Servlet API, implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and register it either with web.xml directly or via the [webxml plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml).

The `ServletContextListener` implementation is supposed to use normal java de-/serialization.

Comment: You mean I have to somehow _manually_ persist the context during `contextDestroyed` and reload it on `contextInitialized`?

Comment: @johanneslink Do not try to persist the ServletContext, there is no way to restore it. It is not meant to be persisted.

Comment: @Stefan The ServletContextListener is supposed to do 'use normal java de-/serialization' for what?

Comment: @Pidster I'm keeping track of all active sessions in servletContext. The sessions remain active after tomcat's restart so I'd like to know about them as well.

Comment: I didn't mean to persist the ServletContext itself but it's attributes via get/setAttribute()

Answer (score 1):

The ServletContext is not persistent and is non-distributable.  It does not implement Serializable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html

Chapter 4 of the Servlet Specification deals with the ServletContext and it does describe any expectation that properties set therein will be persisted.  A database of some sort is usually used for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, serializing the servlet context properties is not a good idea.

The post [Servlet context serializable attribute persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448557/servlet-context-serializable-attribute-persistence) talks about this exactly...

> There is a non-zero chance that the servlet container will terminate abruptly without giving your webapp a chance to persist its attributes.

The properties contained in your servlet context should be treated entirely separately from your web application since they cannot be guaranteed across a container restart (whereas your application's properties can be persisted as you see fit).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "your application's properties"?

Comment: whatever properties you have explicitly set in the servlet context would need to be explicitly persisted throughout the application's lifecycle. So, if you set the attribute "foo" in the servlet context, at some point you will need to persist the value of "foo" to where it can be reloaded into the servlet context on container restart.